# Creating a new objective c class that implement some methods

Tags: objective-c, uicontrol

In an technical phone interview, interviewer asked me to implement MiniButton class like follow and asked me to implement some methods that will do what UIButton method does.

```
@interface MiniButton

-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
-(void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
-(void)_callAllTargets;

@end
```

Above is the only information given to me. I was told that I can not subclass MiniButton from UIButton. Besides I can assume whatever local/private variables if I need any.

How can we implement those methods ?

Comment: Identifiers that start with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: @CarlNorum: As C identifiers, sure. I don't think that applies to obj-c method names though.

Comment: @KevnBallard, it has to - Objective-C is a strict superset of C.  What if the implementation had `#define _CallAllTargets` someplace?

Comment: I don't remember exactly whether it was _Call... or _call...

Comment: Apple reserves method names beginning with an underscore: [Private Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1003829-BCIBDJCA).  But that's not really relevant to this question, since the method names were given to the asker.

Comment: If I answer the question, do I get the job? ;)

Comment: @SumitLonkar There are lots of ways to do this, using fundamental Objective-C and Cocoa facilities.  What have you tried?

Comment: @robmayoff: I did something like this objc_msgSend(id, “action”,...); I guess i panicked and tried to do some cool stuff that I guess I was not suppose too :P

Comment: @PaulLalonde: I am not sure about the job but sure you will go ahead to next round :) *if you answer the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are **not** allowed to make a subclass of `UIControl`, you need to choose a data structure for storing the target/action pairs.  Since a button doesn't normally retain its targets, you can just define a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    __unsafe_unretained id target;
    SEL action;
} TargetAction;
```

You can store these in an `NSMutableArray` by wrapping them in instances of `NSValue`.

The easiest way to invoke an action is using the `performSelector:withObject:`, like this:

```
TargetAction ta;
[valueWrapper getValue:&ta];
[ta.target performSelector:ta.action withObject:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the goal was to make a short cut class of UIControl with factoring away the most common touch event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`:

```
@interface MiniButton : UIControl

-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
-(void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
-(void)_callAllTargets;

@end

@implementation MiniButton
-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    [self addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action{
    [self removeTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) _callAllTargets
{
     [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
@end
```

---

Another option could have been, that he wanted you to extend UIButton. But as UIButton is a so-called class cluster (comparable with a factory), it should not be extended by sub-classing but can be extended by creating a category on UIControl, the parent class of UIButton. Now any instance of any button is extended, no matter what subclass is returned.

---

I think he wanted you to show some knowledge about the fact, that actually UIButton and it real classes are just a small layer on top of UIControl. UIButton has only the reposibility of showing the button's label, image,… . all other things reside in UIControl and it ancestors.

Comment: I was told that I can not override the methods.

Comment: it did not overwrite any methods. The methods you posted do not exists on UIControl.

Comment: and `addTarget:action:forConrolEvents:` and all other I call are UIControl methods, not UIButton.

Comment: I think he wanted you to show some knowledge about the fact, that actually UIButton and it subclasses are just a small layer on top of UIControl. UIButton has only the reposibility of showing the button's label, image,… . all other things reside in UIControl and it ancestors.